# Docker Splash with Scrapy not working

Tags: javascript, docker, scrapy, ubuntu-16.04, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape a website that has javascript enabled with the scrapy-splash plugin.

i have installed splash with docker with these commands i am using **Ubuntu 16.04**

```
$ sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash
$ sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

and i have the running splash docker just like that everything seems okay ***but***

splash throws this error when processing scrapy error

```
2017-07-20 03:03:23+0000 [-] Log opened.
2017-07-20 03:03:23.870491 [-] Splash version: 3.0
2017-07-20 03:03:24.007457 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.3, Twisted 16.1.1, Lua 5.2
2017-07-20 03:03:24.007614 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2017-07-20 03:03:24.007746 [-] Open files limit: 65536
2017-07-20 03:03:24.007879 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2017-07-20 03:03:24.291391 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':911054901', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2017-07-20 03:03:43.425858 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2017-07-20 03:04:09.534239 [-] verbosity=1
2017-07-20 03:04:09.534387 [-] slots=50
2017-07-20 03:04:09.534499 [-] argument_cache_max_entries=500
2017-07-20 03:04:09.534974 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2017-07-20 03:04:09.535774 [-] Site starting on 8050
2017-07-20 03:04:09.535904 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f0e78e18d30>
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
process 1: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
**See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method**
```

i think this part may be the problem

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

**AND ALSO THE WEBSITE IS AN HTTPS WEBSITE**

## IN SCRAPY

i have imported scrapy-splash like this in **scrapy**

```
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
```

and i am making the requests like this

```
yield SplashRequest(link, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_data)
```

instead of

```
yield scrapy.Request(link, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_data)
```

but as usual splash is not processing the requests

what am i doing wrong here? is there something wrong with Ubuntu?

## SCRAPY DEBUG OUTPUT

```
crawl sofaspider -o out.csv
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: sofa)
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'sofa.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'out.csv', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['sofa.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'sofa', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-20 13:03:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-07-20 13:03:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/Sofas.aspx> (referer: None)
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/willoughby-sofa-200326456.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/union-square-sofa-200223105.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/castin-microfiber-sofa-200278403.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/toby-microfiber-leather-look-reclining-sofa-200217215.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/bryant-II-leather-power-reclining-sofa-217282538.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/crosby-sofa-with-chaise-200235097.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/anastasia-sofa-200209167.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/stylus-power-reclining-sofa-202239352.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/cordelia-sofa-200211201.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/ellington-leather-power-reclining-sofa-202291427.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/delano-power-reclining-sofa-200212520.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/quincey-power-reclining-sofa-200215627.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/corliss-sofa-200331104.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/skye-microfiber-power-reclining-sofa-200320074.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/mckinley-sofa-200211302.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2017-07-20 13:04:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.raymourflanigan.com/diana-sofa-200345115.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
```

Comment: Did you try opening Splash console in browser (i.e. pointing browser to port `8050` on host with installed Splash)? Also, could you share Scrapy logs of spider run?

Comment: yes i have tried splash by visiting http://localhost:8050, i will update the question right now

Comment: I also see `qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method` in Splash logs but I am able to render pages from raymourflanigan.com. What are you concurrency levels? Maybe your Splash instance cannot handle the load of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` from Scrapy? Does it chagne anything if you lower concurrency? or enable Autothrottle?

Comment: decreasing concurrent requests to even 1 does not work

Comment: Then you can open a bug on Splash or scrapy-splash with your splash logs and scrapy logs

Comment: i'm not sure is it really a bug or am i doing something wrong

Comment: Take a look [here](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#i-m-getting-lots-of-504-timeout-errors-please-help) about common problems gettings gateway timeouts. Also, I'd first increase log level of Splash (see [here](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#passing-custom-options)).